# Should you use external files to store large data?

Tags: swift, performance, data-storage

I am making an app that uses many large texts that are predefined. At the moment, I am storing them in a RTF file and loading them from there to separate code from content. If the rtf file will have around 1500-2000 lines and it is loaded and split several times when the app launches, will the app need very much time to load and should I define the content in the source-code?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I definitely would not be inclined to put 2000+ lines of text in the source code itself. A separate file (or database or whatever) makes a lot more sense.

Regarding whether the app will require much time to load it, you should simply benchmark it (e.g. put `let start = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()` before the load and `let elapsed = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - start` after, and see how long it takes.

By the way, if iOS, make sure you do this on an actual device, not the simulator to get accurate times. But usually loading a small file like this will be inconsequential regarding time required (e.g. it’s likely still going to be smaller than many images).

I just tested loading a fairly heavily marked up rtf (every word a different color), which was 250kb. Using the `NSAttributedString` initializer that takes a file URL, while it was an order of magnitude slower than a plain text file (same text, no markup), it still only took 70ms on my iPhone. But clearly, you should benchmark your own file.